# How do I deal with ERR! EMFILE: too many open files on PA?

Tags: npm, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my React app on PythonAnywhere. While installing dependencies with `npm i` I'm getting:

> npm ERR! EMFILE: too many open files

I'm using paid account. `ulimit -a` shows `open files (-n) 1024`
When I tried to change it with `ulimit -n 2048` I got `Operation not permitted`

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change ulimits on PythonAnywhere. Have you tried installing your packages in smaller groups?